# How can I recover broken Ubuntu after installing a mismatched version of glibc?

Tags: segmentation-fault, glibc

I'm a newbie on linux. My system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) had a lower version of glibc (possibly 2.2.5?). To install a program requiring a higher glibc, I installed glibc version 2.18 through conda install. 
However, conda and other commands seem broken, showing segmentation fault message. Hence, I'd like to recover it. By searching few posts, I suppose that I have to remove a new version of glibc with a single invocation.
Here's my questions.
1) I cannot be sure what glibc version my system had and if all the files are still there. 
2) How can I recover it? Once again, I'm not very familiar with linux libraries.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I leave this answer for whom having same problem I had.
I do not know how to manually remove glibc, but I found following link:
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/_jkSod9itDE

With "another_miniconda_dir/bin/conda remove --prefix broken_miniconda_dir glibc", I finally fixed my problem!